# Внедрение в клиент-серверное android приложение архитектуры, базовые вопросы

Tags: android, архитектура, клиент-сервер

Я на данный момент занимаюсь разработкой приложения под ОС Android. Это клиент-серверное приложение, которое посылает запросы и получает ответы с сервера, то есть у этого приложения довольно тесная связь с сервером.

Как все на данный момент работает: есть интерфейс в котором прописаны все запросы (`POST`,`DELETE`,`PUT`,`GET`). В каждом запросе используется специальный класс-модель описывающий все поля которые приходят в ответе сервера. Есть куча активити и  фрагментов которые вызывают методы классов-моделей для заполнения экрана разнообразной информацией. У меня есть специальные функции для каждого вида запросов, например для обновления.

По факту сейчас приложение имеет определенный функционал, и вроде работает более-менее стабильно. Но, я недавно столкнулся с статьей, в которой написано что использование архитектуры в разработке под мобильные устройства имеет много преимуществ. Например, если я правильно понял, приложение получает подобие модульности, и все модули независимы между собой. Это означает что при внедрении каких-то значительных изменений не нужно перепиливать весь проект. Я не спорю что это довольно интересная особенность архитектуры.

Сейчас меня начнут заваливать воплями типа "почитай вот статью", или "погугли прежде чем спрашивать такие тупые вопросы". Дорогие господа и дамы, я много искал информации по этому вопросу. Вот например [статья](https://habr.com/post/269135/) на хабре, или [вот](https://habr.com/company/e-Legion/blog/265405/) еще одна. Вроде все понятно написано, куча текста и картинок, но я если честно все-равно не понял. Возможно, у меня уже есть архитектура, я не знаю, но если ее нету, то хотелось бы услышать мнения по поводу ее внедрения. Просто сейчас есть функционал, и возможно архитектура, я не знаю.

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь в этом вопросе. Желательно объяснить просто и на пальцах, потому что я серьезно начинаю задумываться над этим вопросом.

Comment: Возможно есть))
ахахах 
Люди зная что хотят определенную архитектуру, не всегда могут ее построить правильно)
Так что наврядли она сама по себе получится)
А лучше перелопатить несколько статеек и понять что для чего)

Answer (score 2):

Несовсем понятен вопрос. Но постараюсь ответить, по тому как и что понял.

По моему, архитектура это некая концепция или физическая реализация программы для решения конкретной задачи. Все зависит от того, зачем и для чего и для кого вы делаете, какие условия работы, наличие каналов связи, ограничения используемых технологий при разработке, языка разработки и т.д.

Для того чтобы определится нужно ли делать компонентную архитектуру программы, нужно ответить на куча вопросов, к примеру, собираетесь ли вы использовать другие компоненты отдельно друг от друга? Или использовать в других программах?

Comment: нет, модульности в этой программе нету, это единое целое, просто интересовало как именно можно использовать архитектуру, что именно это значит, сейчас мое приложение выполняет поставленную перед ним задачу, но я не использовал никакой архитектуры и никаких концепций при его создании, и это меня немного беспокоит :)

Comment: приветствую. Вы написали "...клиент-серверное приложение", это уже часть архитектуры:) Почему вы приняли решение так разрабатывать? Архитектура и концепция у вас уже есть (см. описание выше что это такое, примерно). Но у вас нет четкого понимания, с точки зрения методик (теории, практики), что у вас получилось и что разработали. У Вас пока нет четкого понимания что такое "архитектура". Поэтому, порекомендую, почитать: 1. что такое архитектура программного средства  2. о методологиях проектирования и разработки программ.